# MySQL Update a table by min of another table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I would like to update Table **Lease** from Table **History**

```
CREATE TABLE Lease
    (`LeaseID` int, `Name` varchar(3), `Users` varchar(15), `WhoSignID` int, `NoteDate` date)
;
    
INSERT INTO Lease
    (`LeaseID`, `Name`, `Users`, `WhoSignID`, `NoteDate`)
VALUES
    (1, 'AAA', '1000,1001', NULL, NULL),
    (2, 'BBB', '1002', NULL, NULL),
    (3, 'CCC', '1003,1004', NULL, NULL),
    (4, 'DDD', '1005,1006, 1007', NULL, NULL)
;

CREATE TABLE History
    (`HistoryID` int, `LeaseID` int, `User` int, `SignDate` date)
;
    
INSERT INTO History
    (`HistoryID`, `LeaseID`, `User`, `SignDate`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1000, '2020-01-05'),
    (2, 1, 1001, '2020-01-04'),
    (3, 1, 1001, '2020-01-02'),
    (4, 1, 1000, '2020-01-03'),
    (6, 2, 1002, '2020-05-01'),
    (7, 2, 1002, '2020-05-03')
;
```

I looking of a Mysql Update to update Table Lease :
NoteDate and WhoSignID based on SignDate and User
where Minimum of SignDate of User

**Table Lease After Update**

```
LeaseID | Name | Users           | WhoSignID | NoteDate 
1       | AAA  | 1000,1001       | 1001      | 2020-01-02
2       | BBB  | 1002            | 1002      | 2020-05-01
...
```

I appreciate any assist

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Strawberry, The SQLFiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32b440/3

Comment: Thanks @Deepak Rai for reformating the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Lease` table has a serious design problem, because it is storing users as a CSV list.  Instead, you should have each user value on a separate record.  That being said, it appears that the CSV user list is immaterial to your current problem, which only required finding the earliest date for each lease.  If so, then a simple update join should suffice:

```sql
UPDATE Lease l
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT h1.LeaseID, h1.User, h2.MinSignDate
    FROM History h1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT LeaseID, MIN(SignDate) AS MinSignDate
        FROM History
        GROUP BY LeaseID
    ) h2
        ON h2.LeaseID = h1.LeaseID AND
           h2.MinSignDate = h1.SignDate
) h
    ON h.LeaseID = l.LeaseID
SET
    WhoSignID = h.User,
    NoteDate = h.MinSignDate;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you are right and this is a design issue, but for now, is there any way to use Mysql : IN or FIND_IN_SET to solve the issue? because I can not change the design.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `FIND_IN_SET`, or what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: Thanks.your answer is correct but ig is only for the date. I would like to know which user also sign first. That's why I asked if we can get the date as well as user of that date to be updated.